# How to call a smart contract function by passing a struct in it

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, javascript, smart-contract-wallets

I would like to call exactInputSingle function of pancakeswap contract:

```
"function exactInputSingle(struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams params) external payable returns (uint256 amountOut)"
```

But I have to pass an struct to call this function.

```
struct ExactInputSingleParams {
    address tokenIn;
    address tokenOut;
    uint24 fee;
    address recipient;
    uint256 amountIn;
    uint256 amountOutMinimum;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96;
}
```

But ethersJs and web3.js doesn't support calling a function by passing a struct.

How to call the function?

I tried calling fnction by directly providing the value rather than a struct as suggested by someone but it didn't worked.

code:

```
const exactInputSingleParams = {
      tokenIn: process.env.YING_ADDRESS_BSC,
      tokenOut: process.env.YANG_ADDRESS_BSC,
      fee: 500,
      recipient: process.env.PUB_KEY,
      amountIn: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1234.0", 18),
      amountOutMinimum: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100.0", 18),
      sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
    };

    const tx = await contractWithSigner.exactInputSingle(
      exactInputSingleParams,
      {
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(200000),
        gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei"),
      }
    );
```

error:

```
Error: unexpected character at position 44 (argument="param", value="struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams params", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:250:21)
    at throwError (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\fragments.js:53:16)
    at parseParamType (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\fragments.js:187:21)
    at ParamType.fromString (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\fragments.js:333:28)
    at D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\fragments.js:343:72
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parseParams (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\fragments.js:343:32)
    at FunctionFragment.fromString (D:\trading bot\0xArbi-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib\fragments.js:756:25) {
  reason: 'unexpected character at position 44',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'param',
  value: 'struct IV3SwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams params'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can go for the  object {} ir  const ExactInputSingleParams={

```
tokenIn:tokenIn,
tokenOut:tokenOut,
fee:fee,
recipient:recipient
amountIn:amountIn
amountOutMinimum: amountOutMinimum
sqrtPriceLimitX96:sqrtPriceLimitX96
```

}

then create an instance using the web3 or ethers with that instance you can fetch the methods like  constgasEstimate=contract.methods.exactInputSingle(ExactInputSingleParams).estimateGas({walletAddress:walletAddress,value:if the function is payable});
const res= contract.methods.exactInputSingle(ExactInputSingleParams).estimateGas({walletAddress:walletAddress,value:if the function is payable,gas});

with this you can pass the struct of the contract in  a key-value pair as an  object.

Answer (score 1):

It accepts a tuple type.

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Test {
    struct StructA{ string name; address _address;}
    StructA _structA;
    constructor(StructA memory structA) {
        _structA = structA;
    }
}
```

Input:  `["hi", '0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4']`

-> Successful deployment

You should provide the values in the order they are specified in the struct, and wrap that list in array to be able to pass a struct instance to smart contract's function using web3.js or ethers.js.

Hope it helps!